# Is there any way to filter tags based on criteria

Tags: git, github, egit, jgit

Hi i have a Git Repo and inside the Repo i have different projects, On each commit i am giving a tag name. Now when i tried to retrieve tag list i am getting all tag names corresponding to that repository with the below code.

```
FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    repositoryBuilder.addCeilingDirectory(new File("D:\\TestRepo"));
repositoryBuilder.findGitDir(new File("D:\\TestRepo\\.git"));
Repository repo = repositoryBuilder.build();

List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, Ref> tags = repo.getTags();
for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> entry : tags.entrySet()) {
     tagList.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Here TestRepo is my Git Repository and inside that i am having different projects like Proj1, Proj2, Proj3.

I have committed Proj1 twice with tag ids P1v1.1 and P1v1.2 respectively and Proj2 with tag id P2v1.1 and Proj3 with tag id P3v1.1.

With the above code i am getting all tag ids like below
[P1v1.1, P1v1.2, P2v1.1, P3v1.1]

But i want to get tag id's specific to the project. Is there any way of getting tag id based on search criteria like if i want for Proj1 then it should give only [P1v1.1, P1v1.2]